# How do I set Avalon.Wizard Icon using MVVM extensions

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wizard

I'm working with [AvalonWizard](https://avalonwizard.codeplex.com/) control library for WPF using the MVVM extensions.

I cannot find a way to set the Icon property of WizardPage through XAML.

Here's my attempt:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ImportFoxPro.Views.StartPageView"
         xmlns:aw="clr-namespace:AvalonWizard;assembly=AvalonWizard"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
         mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="476" d:DesignWidth="720">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="aw:WizardPage">
        <Setter Property="aw:Wizard97.Icon" Value="{StaticResource MyImageSource}"/>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>

</Grid>
```

It gives no error but it doesn't solve my issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add a style to the WizardPage that binds the icon to the DataContext (the ViewModel for that page).  Then, make a IValueConverter that returns the correct icon for the view model.  Not sure how you should go about the second part (public property on the model, configuration values, etc), but that's one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Will, while I've been able to bind the Icon from ViewModel, I was here asking about a pure XAML way to do it.